# Tooltip for each items in a combo box

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox, tooltip

I just want to add a tooltip for each item in a combo box. i am using c#.net windows application.

There is no option like

combobox.items[1].tooltip();

Is there any way to add tooltip it ?

Answer (score 36):

There are actually a couple reasonable solutions to this question. An MSDN forum has a [ComboBox Item highlight event](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e234c4a7-0cf7-4284-a072-8152f7593002/) post that contains two possibilities,
one from nobugz and one from agrobler. Each of them provides code to subclass a ComboBox that is supposed to handle tool tips on individual items in the ComboBox's dropdown. Agrobler's solution looks more polished, in that he/she even includes some nice illustrations, but unfortunately it is not clear (at least to me) how to populate the crucial ToolTipMember property of the control.

Both of these solutions appear to allow arbitrary tooltips assigned to individual items. A more specific, but more common case, is where you simply want the tooltip to mirror the text of the item, when you know you may have items that are too long to fit the width of the ComboBox. In my own case, I have an instance of a ComboBox that holds complete file paths so it is easy to see where the contents could exceed the ComboBox's width.

Zhi-Xin Ye, in the MSDN forum post [Windows Dropdown question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e0418c61-a614-4f0d-8cf4-59cf9cc5bba5/), provides a solution that addresses this more specific problem and is much simpler. I reproduce the code here in its entirety. (Note that this code presupposes you have created a Form called Form1 and hooked up the load handler shown, and also added a ComboBox named comboBox1 and a tool tip handler toolTip1.)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    this.comboBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(comboBox1_DrawItem);
}

void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    string text = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.Items[e.Index]);
    e.DrawBackground();
    using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
    { e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, br, e.Bounds); }

    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
    { this.toolTip1.Show(text, comboBox1, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom); }
    else { this.toolTip1.Hide(comboBox1); }
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

While simple and concise, this code does suffer from one defect (as is pointed out in a reply on the above MSDN thread): as you move the mouse (without clicking) from one dropdown item to the next, only every *other* one shows a persistent tooltip! The fix is only hinted at by yet another entry on that thread, so I thought it would be useful to provide the full, corrected code here:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    comboBox1.DrawItem += comboBox1_DrawItem;
    comboBox1.DropDownClosed += comboBox1_DropDownClosed;
}

private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.Hide(comboBox1);
}

private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index < 0) { return; } // added this line thanks to Andrew's comment
    string text = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.Items[e.Index]);
    e.DrawBackground();
    using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
    { e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, br, e.Bounds); }
    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
    { toolTip1.Show(text, comboBox1, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom); }
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Besides removing a few redundant portions of code (e.g. the "this" qualifier) the primary difference is moving the toolTip1.Hide call into the DropDownClosed event handler. Taking it out of the DrawItem handler eliminates the defect mentioned above; but then you need to close it when the drop down closes, otherwise the last displayed tooltip will remain onscreen.

**2012.07.31 Addendum**

Just wanted to mention that I have since created a composite ComboBox that incorporates  this tooltip capability so if you use my library you have no code to write at all. Just drag a ComboBoxWithTooltip onto the Visual Studio designer and you are done. Drill down to ComboBoxWithTooltip on my [API page](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/api/csharp/) or [download](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/download.html) my open-source C# library to get started. (Note that the patch for the bug Andrew caught will be in release 1.1.04, due out soon.)

Comment: Just a warning... if you have the `DropDownStyle` set to `DropDownList`, this doesn't really work.  If you use `DropDownList`, you will need to make sure that the `e.Index` is greater than -1.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @Andrew! I have amended the code above to avoid the resulting runtime error.

Comment: I tried this (Visual Studio 2013 - .NET 2.0 Project - Windows 8.1) and the text bounds don't seem to go all the way to the right leaving an empty space at the end. Also, with the `DropDownList` `DropDownStyle`, if the list is longer than the drop down window, the tooltip follows the phantom item.

Comment: I found out that using a `StringFormat` with a `Trimming` of `StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter` works fine and looks even better.

Comment: And now there's a positioning problem when it's a *drop up*.

Comment: The positioning problem when the drop down displays upward can be solved by using this link to retrieve the rectangles of the combo box and the combo box list and then adding an offset to the Show call. Here's the comparison http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192096/how-to-check-if-combobox-drop-down-list-is-revealed-up-or-down and here is a sample of how to use windows native code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192680/how-can-i-change-comboboxs-drop-down-list-dynamically-when-its-showed-on-scre

Comment: Minor adjustments to the DrawItem event handler allow the dropdown list and tooltip to have different text.I used a custom class with three properties (Text, Value, Description) to populate the dropdown list. Instead of `string text = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.Items[e.Index]);` to retrieve the text, I use `string toolTip = ((MyClass)comboBox1.Items[e.Index]).Description;`. That got the tooltip text and in a similar manner I got the `Text` value. I used the `Text` value for the `e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, br, e.Bounds);` and the `Description` value for the tooltip.

Comment: Do we need dropdown closed event ?
because if we set the duration property in the show method of the tool tip, I believe we do not need closed event.
toolTip1.Show(text, comboBox1, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom,1000) // where 1000 is 1 sec... this value goes in Milisecond.

Comment: I'm getting a tooltip hanging around even with overriding the `OnDropDownClosed()` method to hide the tooltip.  It seems like `OnDrawItem()` can fire (with `e.Index >= 0`) after `OnDropDownClosed()` if the arrow is used to collapse the dropdown. I added `DroppedDown` to the conditions which shows the tooltip to fix this without a timeout.

Answer (score 10):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
    toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 0;
    toolTip1.InitialDelay = 0;
    toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 0;
    toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.comboBox1, comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString()) ;
}
```

Comment: Although this will work, it will also create a strong connection between the tooltip (which you now have no way of accessing being that you created it without assigning it to a variable). So if you try to remove to comboBox. Although it will remove from sight. It will stay in memory. Not only that, you're compounding ties with new tooltips every time you change index. I'd take the Tooltip to a higher scope and simply call like this:
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
myGolbalToolTip.SetToolTip(this.comboBox1, yourString);

Comment: That way, inside or outside of the scope, you can call myGlobalToolTip.RemoveAll() to remove all connections and then remove the control from memory. But that's only if you're dynamically creating objects.

Comment: Ho do you "remove the control from memory"?

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

```
ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip() { AutoPopDelay = 0, InitialDelay = 0, ReshowDelay = 0, ShowAlways = true, };
comboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
comboBox.DrawItem += (s, e) =>
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    string text = comboBox.GetItemText(comboBox.Items[e.Index]);
    using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, br, e.Bounds);
    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected && comboBox.DroppedDown)
        toolTip.Show(text, comboBox, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom + 4);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
};
comboBox.DropDownClosed += (s, e) =>
    toolTip.Hide(comboBox);
```

Answer (score 1):

Building upon the solution from Michael Sorens (fixed a few bugs and added features).  A few things this does:

- It will display a preview of a file associated with the drop down (in this case a book title from an XML file, or you can add more descriptions in the
  tooltip, or display something completely different).
- It does not display tooltip for the "0" positon in the drop down (I had a placeholder, but you can simply remove the `e.index>0` in the second `if` statement).
- It does not display the tooltip when the dropdown is CLOSED.

  ```
  private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
  {
      ComboBox comboBox1 = (ComboBox)sender;
      if (e.Index >= 0)
      {//Draws all items in drop down menu
          String text = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.Items[e.Index]);
          e.DrawBackground();
          using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
          {
              e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, br, e.Bounds);
          }

          if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected && e.Index > 0 && comboBox1.DroppedDown)
          {//Only draws tooltip when item 1+ are highlighted.  I had a "--" placeholder in the 0 position
              try
              {
                  XmlDocument doc;
                  XmlNode testNode;
                  doc = new XmlDocument();
                  String testXMLDoc = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}.xml", filePath, fileName);//global variables
                  String toolTip = "---Preview of File---";
                  doc.Load(testXMLDoc);
                  testNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Books");
                  if (testNode.HasChildNodes)
                  {
                      XmlNodeList nodeList = testNode.SelectNodes("Book");
                      foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in nodeList)
                      {
                          toolTip += "\r\n" + xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Title").InnerXml;
                      }
                  }
                  this.toolTipHelp.Show(toolTip, comboBox1, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom);
              }
              catch (Exception tp)
              {
                  Debug.WriteLine("Error in comboBox1 tooltip: " + tp);
              }
          }
          else
          {
              this.toolTipHelp.Hide(comboBox1);
          }
      }
      else
      {
          this.toolTipHelp.Hide(comboBox1);
      }
      e.DrawFocusRectangle();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx).

Having a ToolTip for each item in a combobox is an unusual requirement; perhaps you could use a 2 column combobox instead?

Comment: How do you do a two-column combo?

Comment: There are a few free ones around. Found this one on codeproject but I haven't used it and I can't comment on how good it is: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/multicolumncombo.aspx

Comment: I don't think this is unusual at all.  The common situation is if the item's text is too long and you can't see the tail of the string.  A tool tip is a very obvious way of displaying the item. A two-column combo sounds clunky and awful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading from a datasource, get the data into datatable and set the same to combobox.
My datatable has three columns ID,NAME,DEFINITION. Below is my code :

```
InputQuery = "select * from ds_static_frequency";
        TempTable = UseFunc.GetData(InputQuery);

        cmbxUpdateFrequency.DataSource = TempTable;
        cmbxUpdateFrequency.DataTextField = "NAME";
        cmbxUpdateFrequency.DataValueField = "ID";
        cmbxUpdateFrequency.DataBind();

        foreach (DataRow dr in TempTable.Rows)
        {                
            int CurrentRow = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"].ToString());
            cmbxUpdateFrequency.Items[CurrentRow - 1].ToolTip = dr["Definition"].ToString();               
        }
```

Comment: Wrong! There is no "ToolTip" property on the winform combobox item.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
public class ToolTipComboBox: ComboBox
{
    #region Fields

    private ToolTip toolTip;
    private bool _tooltipVisible;
    private bool _dropDownOpen;
    #endregion

    #region Types

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
    public struct COMBOBOXINFO
    {
        public Int32 cbSize;
        public RECT rcItem;
        public RECT rcButton;
        public ComboBoxButtonState buttonState;
        public IntPtr hwndCombo;
        public IntPtr hwndEdit;
        public IntPtr hwndList;
    }

    public enum ComboBoxButtonState
    {
        // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global
        StateSystemNone = 0,
        // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global
        StateSystemInvisible = 0x00008000,
        // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global
        StateSystemPressed = 0x00000008
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hWnd, ref COMBOBOXINFO pcbi);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private IntPtr HwndCombo
    {
        get
        {
            COMBOBOXINFO pcbi = new COMBOBOXINFO();
            pcbi.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(pcbi);
            GetComboBoxInfo(Handle, ref pcbi);
            return pcbi.hwndCombo;
        }
    }

    private IntPtr HwndDropDown
    {
        get
        {
            COMBOBOXINFO pcbi = new COMBOBOXINFO();
            pcbi.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(pcbi);
            GetComboBoxInfo(Handle, ref pcbi);
            return pcbi.hwndList;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public new DrawMode DrawMode
    {
        get { return base.DrawMode; }
        set { base.DrawMode = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ctor

    public ToolTipComboBox()
    {
        toolTip = new ToolTip
        {
            UseAnimation = false,
            UseFading = false
        };

        base.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        DrawItem += OnDrawItem;
        DropDownClosed += OnDropDownClosed;
        DropDown += OnDropDown;
        MouseLeave += OnMouseLeave;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void OnDropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dropDownOpen = true;
    }

    private void OnMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResetToolTip();
    }

    private void ShowToolTip(string text, int x, int y)
    {
        toolTip.Show(text, this, x, y);
        _tooltipVisible = true;
    }

    private void OnDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cbo = sender as ComboBox;
        if (e.Index == -1) return;

        // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
        string text = cbo.GetItemText(cbo.Items[e.Index]);
        e.DrawBackground();

        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, e.Font, e.Bounds.Location, SystemColors.Window);

            if (_dropDownOpen)
            {
                Size szText = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, cbo.Font);
                if (szText.Width > cbo.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth && !_tooltipVisible)
                {
                    RECT rcDropDown;
                    GetWindowRect(HwndDropDown, out rcDropDown);

                    RECT rcCombo;
                    GetWindowRect(HwndCombo, out rcCombo);

                    if (rcCombo.Top > rcDropDown.Top)
                    {
                        ShowToolTip(text, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y - rcDropDown.Rect.Height - cbo.ItemHeight - 5);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ShowToolTip(text, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + cbo.ItemHeight - cbo.ItemHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ResetToolTip();
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, e.Font, e.Bounds.Location, cbo.ForeColor);
        }

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }

    private void OnDropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dropDownOpen = false;
        ResetToolTip();
    }

    private void ResetToolTip()
    {
        if (_tooltipVisible)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
            toolTip.SetToolTip(this, null);
            _tooltipVisible = false;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is c# code to show tool tip on item of combo box whose width is greater than width of combo box control. Tool tip will be shown once user hover on such combo box:

```
 this.combo_box1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
 this.combo_box1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
 this.combo_box1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(combo_box1_DrawItem);
 this.combo_box1.DropDownClosed += new EventHandler(combo_box1_DropDownClosed);
 this.combo_box1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(combo_box1_Leave);

 void combo_box1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Index < 0) { return; }
            string text = combo_box1.GetItemText(combo_box1.Items[e.Index]);
            e.DrawBackground();
            using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, br, e.Bounds);
            }

            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected && combo_box1.DroppedDown)
            {
                if (TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, combo_box1.Font).Width > combo_box1.Width)
                {
                    toolTip1.Show(text, combo_box1, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom);
                }
                else
                {
                    toolTip1.Hide(combo_box1);
                }
            }
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }

        private void combo_box1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTip1.Hide(combo_box1);
        }

        private void combo_box1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTip1.Hide(combo_box1);
        }

        private void combo_box1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!combo_box1.DroppedDown && TextRenderer.MeasureText(combo_box1.SelectedItem.ToString(), combo_box1.Font).Width > combo_box1.Width)
            {
                toolTip1.Show(combo_box1.SelectedItem.ToString(), combo_box1, combo_box1.Location.X, combo_box1.Location.Y);
            }
        }
```

Here is the link for more details - 
http://newapputil.blogspot.in/2016/12/display-tooltip-for-combo-box-item-cnet.html

Answer (score 0):

With WPF use a ComboBox.ItemTemplate

```xml
<ComboBox               
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboBoxItemViewModels}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedComboBoxItem, 
    SelectedValuePath="Name"                
>
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```