# How to check if combobox drop down list is revealed up or down?

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, drop-down-menu

I have control (implemented C#, .Net 2.0) that inherits from combobox. It has filtering and other stuff. To keep UI right, when amount of items during filtering falls, drop down list changes its size to fit the number of items left (it is done by NativeMethods.SetWindowPos(...)).

Is there any way to check if drop down list is revealed up or down (literally) - not to check if it is open, it is open, but in which direction, upwards or downwards?

cheers, jbk

Comment: You'll also need GetWindowRect() to find out where it is.

Comment: Yes i have found an answer, but i need to wait 8 hours to post it, because do not have at least 100 points :) Shortly get handles to combo and dropdown, get rectangle from them, and compare both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i found an answer:

Here we have both handles to combobox:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a handle to the combobox
    /// </summary>
    private IntPtr HwndCombo
    {
        get
        {
            COMBOBOXINFO pcbi = new COMBOBOXINFO();
            pcbi.cbSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(pcbi);
            NativeMethods.GetComboBoxInfo(this.Handle, ref pcbi);
            return pcbi.hwndCombo;
        }
    }
```

And to dropdownlist of combobox:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a handle to the combo's drop-down list
    /// </summary>
    private IntPtr HwndDropDown
    {
        get
        {
            COMBOBOXINFO pcbi = new COMBOBOXINFO();
            pcbi.cbSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(pcbi);
            NativeMethods.GetComboBoxInfo(this.Handle, ref pcbi);
            return pcbi.hwndList;
        }
    }
```

Now, we can get rectangles from handles:

```
    RECT comboBoxRectangle;
    NativeMethods.GetWindowRect((IntPtr)this.HwndCombo, out comboBoxRectangle);
```

and

```
    // get coordinates of combo's drop down list
    RECT dropDownListRectangle;
    NativeMethods.GetWindowRect((IntPtr)this.HwndDropDown, out dropDownListRectangle);
```

now we can check:

```
    if (comboBoxRectangle.Top > dropDownListRectangle.Top)
    {
         ....
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

The ComboBox has two events (`DropDown` and `DropDownClosed`) that are fired when the dropdown part opens and closes, so you might want to attach handlers to them to monitor the state of the control.

Alternatively, there's also a boolean property (`DroppedDown`) which should tell you the current state.

Comment: Yes, but actually I would like to know if dropdown is revealed up or down (literally). I mean that i know when combo is revealed, but it can reveal to up or down depends of combobox position on screen.

Comment: Oh, you mean whether the dropdown list portion is being displayed above or below the text field?

Comment: I don't know if there is a clean way of doing that. I just poked around a bit and it would be possible to get the HWND of the drop down via reflection (a private field named `dropDownHandle`) and then use a Windows API call to get its location on the screen - but that seems like a pretty nasty hack, I certainly would not want to do something like that in production code :)

Answer (score 3):

ComboBoxes open downwards or upwards depending on the space they have to open: if they have avaliable space below them they'll open downwards as usual, if not they'll open upwards.

So you simply have to check if they have space enough below them to know. Try this code:

```
void CmbTestDropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point p = this.PointToScreen(cmbTest.Location);
    int locationControl = p.Y; // location on the Y axis
    int screenHeight = Screen.GetBounds(new Point(0,0)).Bottom; // lowest point
    if ((screenHeight - locationControl) < cmbTest.DropDownHeight)
        MessageBox.Show("it'll open upwards");
    else MessageBox.Show("it'll open downwards");
}
```

Comment: Thanks by solution, but here I would like to add a little enhancements: The DropDownHeight wasn't measure properly so I ever get the size "Items.Count * ItemHeight" and the locationControl should be "p.Y + cmbTest.Bottom" to cover all screen