# How To Add Tooltip to Combobox Item in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

How can we add tooltip to combobox items,  so when a user moves around items can see tooltip, items in combobox will be of type string and the same value will be displayed as tooltip

Comment: Maybe this can help you to find something:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680373/tooltip-for-each-items-in-a-combo-box

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1197361/lukinha-rs thanks for the suggestion, I got the output as expected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tooltip for each items in a combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680373/tooltip-for-each-items-in-a-combo-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle DrawItem event of the ComboBox which will be raised when a visual aspect of an owner-drawn ComboBox changes. You can refer to the following site which contains a very detailed sample.

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3471498&SiteID=1

Comment: @dipesh-bhattatt : for the link I got the expected output