# Display a tooltop for each item in a combobox list

Tags: vb.net, combobox, tooltip

My application has a form on which the user enters an address. The database design constraints being placed upon me as a developer require that I make the user enter each component of the address (Number, Street Name, Street Type, Directional, etc...) separately.

Because of the sheer number of Street Types recognized by the USPS, I have all of them in a database with both the long-form name and the abbreviation that populates a combobox control.  Because some of the abbreviations are a bit obscure, I want a tooltip (or other like-functioning process) to display the long-form name of the abbreviation when the mouse passes over the abbreviation in the drop-down.

I have searched previous questions, but can't find anything that pertains specifically to my situation.  Any assistance with a strategy for tackling this problem would be greatly appreciated.

My application is being developed in Visual Studio 2013 in Visual Basic.

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: since the CBO can store objects, you could create a Class comprised of `{Abbrev, LongName}` add them to the cbo, show the long name (getting rid of the need for a tooltip), but return the Abbreviation to the code.  or make it ownerdraw, show the abbrev, but in the DrawItem event, popup a tooltip with the related LongName from the class.  That will only show it when it is selected though as there isnt a ItemMouseHover event I know of.  Go with A.

Comment: A quick look around the combobox control and I'm not seeing anything.
You will most likely have to create your own control that overrides the mouse enter event of each list item.

Comment: Plutonix: Thanks for the response!  That is definitely one way to do a work-around.  If I can't get it to work the way I outlined, then I will try it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680373/tooltip-for-each-items-in-a-combo-box/5053730#5053730 addresses the issue in C#, but I'm working in VB.  Going to look over the code and see if I can come up with a solution.

Comment: that suffers from exactly what I said: you have to **select** the item to get it to show the tooltip - not exactly what you asked for or what a user expects.  see: `if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)`.  there is no itemhover event