# Create ToolTip for ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

I can not see the full names of the data in the C # form application because I can not extend the width of the ComboBox due to the design of my screen.

Before I make a selection, I want to show it in the ComboBox as shown below. How do I do this in the combo box?

[image]

Comment: I think what are you trying to say is  ToolTip

Comment: So you want a tooltip? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5053730/7104041) is pretty nice explanation how to do it

Comment: I don't see a ComboBox only a DataGridView. - And: You do know about  [ComboBox.DropDownWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) ?? (Like a tooltip (which is what you show ) it will extend the dropdown beyond the form border)

Comment: I guess I found
http://www.techcognition.com/post/C-Win-Forms-Tooltip-for-ComboBox-Items

Comment: Yes, an option but hardly any  better than simply making the built-in DropDownwidth wider. Also, please change the misleading title; a MessageBox must always be close by the ser; surely not what you really want..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to get an event that fires when highlighting changes but if it can be enough to update when the selection changes this should do it

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ToolTip tt;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("item1");
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("item2");
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("item3");
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("item4");
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("item5");
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("item6");

        this.comboBox1.MouseEnter += this.ComboBox1_MouseEnter;
        this.comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += this.ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged;

        this.tt = new ToolTip
        {
            AutoPopDelay = 0,
            InitialDelay = 0,
            ReshowDelay = 500,
            ShowAlways = true
        };

        this.tt.SetToolTip(this.comboBox1, "");
    }

    private void ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tt.SetToolTip(this.comboBox1, this.comboBox1.SelectedText);
    }

    private void ComboBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tt.SetToolTip(this.comboBox1, this.comboBox1.SelectedText);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
from inspecting a combobox in runtime I don't think you will be able to even get the highlighted text nor a event that fires when it changes. Also there are no directly accessible subControls or anything that could be useful for the behaviour you described in your question. I haven't looked into the possibilities using reflection but most of the times these solutions turn out to be more of a problem than an actual solution. Another way of achieving the behaviour will most likely be to use WPF or making your own comboBox control.

Comment: I want the same as I give below.       https://bahadirsahin.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/dgiewrowchngclr.jpg