# Issue in setting combobox.dropdownwidth to max width in datagridviewcombobox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcombobox

I have a datagridview combobox column. I need to dynamically adjust the width of combobox to the longest string width, so that user can read lengthy string in the combobox item.
My code is

```
            int width = comboBox.DropDownWidth;
            Graphics g = comboBox.CreateGraphics();
            Font font = comboBox.Font;
            int vertScrollBarWidth =
                (comboBox.Items.Count > comboBox.MaxDropDownItems)
                ? SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth : 0;

            int newWidth;
            foreach (string s in ((ComboBox)sender).Items)
            {
                newWidth = (int)g.MeasureString(s, font).Width
                    + vertScrollBarWidth;
                if (width < newWidth)
                {
                    width = newWidth;
                }
            }
            comboBox.DropDownWidth = width;
```

But this not working. I dont think there is any problem with the code but still the width is not changed. Do I have to change any property of datagridview in order to change the width?

Comment: You can use tooltip of combobox to make it more readable.

Comment: Can you help me with tooltip. i have tried using this code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680373/tooltip-for-each-items-in-a-combo-box%3C/a%3E

Comment: But some problem in displaying text. Sometimes black color appears in tooltip and couldn't see tooltip text too

Comment: Better to use a horizontal scrolling view.